# Python assign value X if variable V is 1, Y if it is 43,

Tags: python

I have a variable V which takes values { 1, 43, ... } and I would like to assign to variable Z values { X1, X2, ... } based on which exact value V has taken. Example: if V is 1, Z is X1. If V is, unexpectedly, not part of the set of defined values, the behaviour can be "undefined".

Basically, I don't know how to do a switch statement in Python. In the manual, I did not find "switch".

Comment: And what have you tried? What are you having problems with?

Comment: I am surprised by the downvotes but I take them as a "lesson". :) No comment and just downvote is not helping me to learn though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
z_values = {
    1: X1,
    42: X2,
    }

Z = z_values[V]
```

You haven't said what you want to happen if V is not one of the valid values.

Comment: This does evaluate `X1` and `X2` though, which could be function calls with side effects or whatever. I think a simple if-case would be clearer, and it’s obviously something OP didn’t think of.

Comment: I was using `X1` and `X2` as generically as the OP used them.  With more information, I can give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if v == 1:
    z = 'x1'
elif v == 42:
    z = 'x2'
```

Unless I completely misunderstood what you want, you are asking for a simple if-statement…?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple "If X then Y else Z" (`x ? y : z` in many other languages) then this should work:

```
target = y if x else z
```

If what you want is basically a switch, then something like this should work:

```
def func_x():
    print "x"
def func_y():
    print "y"
def func_z():
    print "z"
def default():
    print "nope"
{
    "x": func_x,
    "y": func_y,
    "z": func_z
}.get(input, default)()
```

Comment: I've never understood peoples' attraction to this construct.  It isn't more compact than a simple if/elif ladder, requires naming all those little functions, and creates new inconvenient scopes.